# How to shoot at the enemy that is farest forward?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay so this has been bugging me all day so I thought I would post it here. This is such a specific topic that it was basically impossible to find any sort of references on how this would be done.

```
for (var i:int=0; i<=Main.bloonList.length-1; i++)
{
    //loop through the children in enemyHolder
    var cEnemy = Main.bloonList[i];//define a movieclip that will hold the current child
    //this simple formula with get us the distance of the current enemy
    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cEnemy.y - this.y,2) + Math.pow(cEnemy.x - this.x,2)) < 100)
    {
        shoot(cEnemy);
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

This is the code  i have at the moment and i would like to know how to figure out which enemy is the farest along the track. I can find it by using this.

```
function onEnter(e:Event)
{
    distanceTravelled=distanceTravelled+xSpeed+Yspeed
}
```

But how can I tell the for loop to target the one with the highest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the furthest enemy after looping all enemies.  At the end shoot.

**pseudocode**

```
var maxDistance = 0; 
var furthesEnemy = null;
var currentDistance = null;

for (var i:int=0; i<=Main.bloonList.length-1; i++) {

    //loop through the children in enemyHolder
    var cEnemy = Main.bloonList[i];

    //this simple formula with get us the distance of the current enemy
    currentDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cEnemy.y - this.y,2) + Math.pow(cEnemy.x - this.x,2));

    if (currentDistance > maxDistance) {
        maxdistance = currentDistance;
        furthesEnemy = cEnemy;
    }
}

shoot(furthesEnemy);
```

Comment: I'd recommend storing the current distance in a local variable. e.g. `curDistance = Math.sqrt(...);` then you can do `if(curDistance > maxDistance) { maxDistance = curDistance }` without having to recalculate it.

Comment: Sure.. Focused on the issue.

Comment: Weirdly shoots every bloon. Never.Never mind, my fault for copy pasting :)

Answer (score 2):

Just find the highest distance value by updating a new variable (say for example `highestDistEnemy`) inside your current for loop. You initialize the variable with the first enemy `MovieClip` object, and only update it to a new enemy object when that enemy's distance is greater than the previous `highestDistEnemy`'s distance. In code:

```
if(distance(curEnemyDistance) > distance(highestDistEnemy)) {
   highestDistEnemy = curEnemy;
}
```

where distance just calculates distance as you're already calculating it and initialize `highestDistEnemy` to `Main.bloonList[0]` at the start of the loop.

Comment: Could you show some example code for the second part because i don't follow you?